# I am having trouble understanding a compiling error /bin/sh: 1: ./a.out: not found with hello world script

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++

When I use the well known hello world script.  I FINALLY got everything in place and fixed all the errors but when I compile this new error pops up telling me this      /bin/sh: 1: ./a.out: not found.

My script looks like this for the hello.ccp file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
 }
```

while my makefile looks like this:

```
hello.ccp:
    g++ -std=gnu++11    hello.cpp
```

Any ideas? thank you so much!

Comment: I'm guessing your makefile is a little more than that. How do you try to run the program?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed issues with the makefile but have a new error:  makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brush up on the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax). The *target* is `a.out`, since that's what you want to *create*. So change `hello.ccp` to `a.out`. Since `hello.cpp` is a *prerequisite* of `a.out`, the Makefile needs to look like this:

```
a.out: hello.cpp
    g++ -std=gnu++11 hello.cpp
```

Also, make sure you're using tabs, not spaces, to indent recipes. Makefiles require tabs.

Comment: I fixed both of those things but it still is showing up with the error

Comment: @Gsachs My answer should be completely fixed now. What's the error?

Comment: thank you, I changed it to exactly that but now it says:   makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.      @user5684998 it fixed the original error though so thank you!

Comment: It would be easier if we saw the actual makefile.

Comment: @Gsachs It makes you have a typo in one of your [static patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html).

Comment: a.out: hello.cpp:
 g++ -std=gnu++11 hello.cpp